# How to increment as 001,002 etc In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, export, bcp, files

i have created an sp to export scripts i stored in a table to text files. What this sp do is if I give 100 as count then each file will have 100 scripts from the table. i am saving the file name as objects_1 ,objects_2 and so on. But what I need is . If I have 100 files. Then the 1st file should be names as objects_001 ,objects_002 , and the last file should be objects_100 . Can someone suggest an idea to do that . ,And please confirm this sp logic is correct .
Thanks.

```
alter PROCEDURE USP_GenerateFile_Packets_new(@count int)
AS 
BEGIN 


DECLARE @ExportQry NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @ExportPath NVARCHAR(100)
SET @ExportPath='C:\Upgrade\Scripts\'
DECLARE @BCPFileName NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ReturnValue NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @K INT=1

declare @minval int=(select min(id) from vsl.ScriptTable)
--DECLARE @I INT=(SELECT COUNT(*) from [UpgradeDB].vsl.ScriptTable)
declare @count1 int=(select @count-1)
 WHILE @minval <=  (SELECT max(id) from [UpgradeDB].vsl.ScriptTable)
 
    BEGIN
        SET @ExportQry = 'SELECT TOP '+convert(nvarchar(100),@count)+' script FROM [UpgradeDB].vsl.ScriptTable where id>='+convert(nvarchar(100),@minval)+' and id<='+convert(nvarchar(100),@minval)+'+'+convert(nvarchar(100),@count1)+' order by id' 

        SET @sql = 'bcp "' + @ExportQry + ' " queryout ' + @ExportPath +  'OBJECTS_'+convert(nvarchar(100),@k)+'.txt -c -t^| -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME;

    --select @sql
        EXEC @ReturnValue =  master..xp_cmdshell @sql


   SET @minval=@minval+@COUNT
   set @k=@k+1   
   END

END

--USP_GenerateFile_Packets_new 1500
```

Comment: alternatively you could do something similar to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/318399/22336)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `SET @sql` with this. This format the @k to the requested format.

```
SET @sql = 'bcp "' + @ExportQry + ' " queryout ' + @ExportPath +  'OBJECTS_'+RIGHT(CONCAT('000',@k), 3)+'.txt -c -t^| -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME;
```

Comment: could u please look into this ?. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/337688/why-offset-fetch-causing-performance-issues-with-queries-in-ms-sql-2019

Answer (score 1):

Adding some changes to [Peter's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/322190/22336)

```
SET @sql = 'bcp "' + @ExportQry + ' " queryout ' + @ExportPath +  'OBJECTS_'+RIGHT(CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', @len),@k), @len)+'.txt -c -t^| -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME
```

@len should be the length of the number of files .